# I'm getting error like this how can i solve that one Variable 'b' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

Tags: ios, xcode

```
func practiceCode() {

    let a = 20
    var b = 0
    print("a: \(a)")
    print("b: \(b)")
}
```

I'm getting error like this how can i solve that one
Variable 'b' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

Comment: Swift is a language that emphasizes safety. If we are not changing the value, using constants (`let`) is more prudent than using variables (`var`), as it’s easier to reason about our code, we can avoid unintended consequences, and the compiler can do additional optimizations. So whenever the compiler sees you using a local variable when you could have used a constant, it will warn you, suggesting that you consider using the constant.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all, really - since you never change `b` after declaring it, there's no reason to use `var`, and you can use `let` instead:

```
let b = 0
```